# Implementing Redux functionality using Context and Reducers in React not working Properly

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

So i am trying to implement the functionality of redux using only react hooks as shown in the following links https://codeburst.io/global-state-with-react-hooks-and-context-api-87019cc4f2cf & https://www.sitepoint.com/replace-redux-react-hooks-context-api/ But I cant seem to get it to work properly for some reason. I am trying to implement a basic setup where the DO_ACTION action is dispatched when button is clicked and the counter global state is shown below the button. When I do click on the increment action button after clicking it a few times, I get undefined for some reason. What am I doing wrong here?

Before clicking
[image]

After clicking 3 or 4 times
[image]

[image]

Here is my folder structure just in case you think i am importing wrong stuff

[image]

Button component

```
import './Button.css';
import React, {useEffect, useContext} from 'react';
import {Context} from '../../store/Store.js';

const Button = ( props ) => {

const [state, dispatch] = useContext(Context);

const incrementAction = () => {
    dispatch({
        type:'DO_ACTION',
        payload: 1
    })
    console.log(state.number);
  };

return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={() => incrementAction()}>Display Number!!!!</button>
        <div>{state.number}</div>
    </div>
    )
};

export default Button
```

here is my reducer

```
const Reducer = (state, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case 'DO_ACTION':
        return state + action.payload
    }
};

export default Reducer;
```

Here is my global store and HOC

```
import React, {createContext, useReducer} from "react";
import Reducer from './Reducer';


const initialState = {
    number: 5
};

const Store = ({children}) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, initialState);
    
    return (
        <Context.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
            {children}
        </Context.Provider>
    )
};

export const Context = createContext(initialState);
export default Store;
```

And here is my main App component that is wrapped with store to have it accessible throughout my app

```
import Store from './store/Store.js';
import Button from './components/Button/Button.js';

const App = () => {

    return (
        <div>
          <Store>
            <Button />
            <OtherComponents /> //a bunch of other components go here like title, paging etc
          </Store>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I realized that in the code for the reducer, i do return state + action.payload, whereas in fact should be return state.number + action.payload. I have fixed that issue, but I still get undefined and the number is not displayed underneath the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be returning the whole (cloned) state object from your reducer function, not just the property you want to update. You should also make sure you have a default case:

```
const Reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'DO_ACTION':
            return {
                number: state.number + action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default Reducer;
```

If you have more than one property in your state object you must remember to clone all of the other properties into it as well (e.g. `{...state, number: state.number + action.payload}`).

Comment: Ahh i see i see. K thanks that got it to work. Note to self for future reference, ALWAYS CHANGE STATE IMMUTABLY! And this website (https://medium.com/@housecor/handling-state-in-react-four-immutable-approaches-to-consider-d1f5c00249d5) has all the ways in which I can change state immutably